# How to redirect output from java to matlab

Tags: matlab, redirect, interface, jar

I have a compiled .JAR file which gets two datasets as input and results in some scores (real numbers). The outputs are printed in console (cmd prompt env.). However I want to call the function multiple times whitin my matlab code. I have no access to the source code of JAR file. Is there any efficient way (probably other than using files) to get the results of jar file back to matlab.

Sample JAR outputs:

---

a: 82.212 %

b: 0 %

c: 0.003 %

---

d: 13.471 %

e: 4.809 %

---

I want these 5 numbers. They are always printed in the same format.

Is there any way I can redirect these results for example to a TCP/IP port that matlab can read the results?

Thanks

Comment: how do you call java, what is the method's interface? how large are the input datasets?

Comment: I use system function in matlab. It is interesting for me to know if I can redirect the result from jar to some think other than a file (for example a tcp/ip port) and then read the results from matlab. The data set is not an issue, only the results are important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second output `result` from `system()` function. It will contain the required output string that you need to parse.

```
[status, result] = system('command');
```

Now, assuming you have the `result` string, here how you can parse it into vector of values:

```
names = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}';
values = nan(size(names));
for k = 1 : length(names)
    idx = strfind(result, names{k});
    assert(numel(idx) == 1);
    values(k) = sscanf(result(idx + length(names{k}) + 1 : end), '%f');
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the answer. I suggest to define idx as an array and use "idx[k] = strfind(result(idx(k-1)+1):end, names{k});". This makes it possible to handle more complicated situations. Thanks

Comment: i'm sure that parsing the string can be done much more efficiently, this is just an example. You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to consider is to link the JAR in to your Matlab program by putting it on the javaclasspath. Then you can call methods on any of the public objects defined in the JAR directly from your M-code. If there's an appropriate entry point to calculate those values, you could call the calculation method directly instead of going through the JAR's `main`, and avoid the overhead of shelling out to a separate JVM process and parsing the output. If you end up calling it a lot, it'll be more efficient.

Comment: I have decompiled JAR file and it produced some JAD files. Now i'm googling about integrating matlab and java as You said above.

Comment: The "External Interfaces" section of the Matlab documentation (in the Help browser or on Mathworks' site) has the info on this. Here's a good place to start: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html

Comment: I agree that using Java objects & methods directly from Matlab is better way than using `system()` call

Comment: You don't need to decompile the JAR, just add it to Matlab's Java class path like this: javaaddpath(fullfile(pwd,'Jar','MyJarName.jar')); (assuming  your jar is called MyJarName.jar and resides in Jar directory in current working directory). The you can simply instantiate Java classes in a similar way as Matlab classes, e.g. myInstance = org.foo.bar.SomeJavaClass(); (include the package name of the class). Then you can call the methods of the Java class directly, e.g. myInstance.someMethod();